# How to overload Form_MouseWheel() in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

How do I overload the `Form_MouseWheel(ByVal Page As Boolean, ByVal Count As Long)` so that when a user scrolls nothing happens?

I don't want to disable the mouse wheel. I want to have the scroll wheel do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278379

Some discussion : http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=192036

A newer solution : http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=A-new-method-for-disabling-the-Mouse-Scroll-Wheel-in-Access-forms

Answer (score 1):

The solution I always used to prevent the mouse wheel scrolling through all records in Access 2003 was to make sure that my forms record source only ever contained 1 record. That way when the user scrolls the mouse wheel there are no more records for Access to scroll though.

E.G. if I had a form for managing customers I would also have a combobox that allowed the user to select from a list of existing customers. After a customer has been selected the forms record source would be updated to only show the customer that had been selected.

You will have to play around with some other properties such as AllowAdditions to cater for cases where you only want to add a new record rather than view an existing record but this is much better (IMO) than distributing a separate DLL or using someone else's code that I didn't fully understand.

A nice side effect of this approach is that your forms should perform much better as you are not loading all records into the form.

Answer (score 0):

IThe answer can be found here:

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/forms/wheel.php

Follow all the instructions and no more record scrolling in your forms. One small note:
If you have a checkbox on your form and focus this checkbox, the scrolling is back. Minor issue and also appearing in my projects.

Success!